# Binominal distribution OR

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

I got this exercise:

> In a multiple choice quiz there are 5 questions and 4 choices for each question (a, b, c, d). Robin has not studied for the quiz at all, and decides to randomly guess the answers. What is the probability that:
>
> she gets exactly 3 or exactly 4 questions right?

Should I understand this question as getting the EXACT value of 3 and EXACT value of 4, and then plus them together? Or is the question just calculating the EXACT for both 3 and 4? Right now I have just done a normal binomial calculation for exactly 3.

Comment: Well, you'll probably need to compute the exactly $3$ and exactly $4$ cases separately but then, yes.  It looks like they want you to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of questions correct is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p = 1/4).$ The four-place PDF (or PMF) table for this distribution can be found using R statistical software as follows (ignore row numbers in brackets `[ ]`):

```
x = 0:5;  pdf = round(dbinom(x, 5, 1/4), 4)
cbind(x, pdf)

     x    pdf
[1,] 0 0.2373
[2,] 1 0.3955
[3,] 2 0.2637
[4,] 3 0.0879  # P(X=3)
[5,] 4 0.0146  # P(X=4)
[6,] 5 0.0010
```

My interpretation of the English is that two separate
probabilities are requested. If asking for the sum, 
the question might have said "... either 3 or 4 questions right." But unless this is an online
computer quiz, there seems to harm in giving the two
numbers *and* their sum to be sure.

You should make sure you know how to use the binomial
PDF formula $P(X = k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k},$ for $k = 0, \dots, n.$ (I would not use a normal approximation for a binomial probability with such a small $n).$

[image]

Comment: To be fair, the question is genuinely ambiguous--perhaps either written by a non-native speaker of English or by a native speaker goaded by non-mathematical copy editor say this. To ask clearly for two probabilties, it should be something like "... probability of exactly 3 questions right and probability of exactly 4 right."

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the key conjunctions for the operations: AND means multiply, OR means add.

Thus, if we let $X$ be a random variable counting the number of correct answers, then $$P(X = 3 \ \text{or}\ X = 4) = P(X=3) + P(X=4).$$